# Where's the community wiki checkbox

Tags: support, community-wiki

I was trying to mark a question I asked as CW, but don't see the community wiki checkbox.  Where is it?

Comment: I saw your question and was wondering the same thing :)

Comment: IS GONE! 6chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been made into a moderator-only feature:

- [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67039/146318)
- [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action/67582#67582)

If you want to post a CW question, post it as normal and flag for moderator attention.